# ¿Cómo reemplazar valores repetidos en una lista?

Tags: python

Me piden escribir un procedimiento que acepte como parámetro un vector que contiene números positivos, que puede contener valores duplicados, y reemplace cada elemento repetido por -1 (menos uno). El procedimiento debe retornar el vector modificado y la cantidad de veces que fue modificado.           yo lo hice así:

```
vector = [1,2,3,4,4,3] 
for i in range(0,6): 
    if vector[i] == vector[i]: 
       vector[i] = -1 
print(vector)
```

pero me remplaza todos los números por -1 no solo los repetidos.

Comment: Hola Ángel. Las preguntas de este tipo, sin código, y que parecen ejercicios de clase suelen ser mal recibidas. Por favor, añade el código que hayas intentado hasta el momento para que podamos ayudarte, ok?

Comment: Además ya has hecho esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403191/como-resolver-el-siguiente-problema-de-python, por que abrir otra?. Por favor lee los enlaces que te dimos en tu pregunta anterior para entender como funciona el sitio. Entiendo que puede ser frustrante, pero ten un poco de paciencia y lee como funciona el sitio.

Comment: el codigo que hice hasta ahora esta en la parte donde dice yo lo hice asi

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de editar tu pregunta, por que entiendo las dificultades que estás teniendo. Revisa los cambios que hice, y sobre todo verifica el formateo del código para ver si efectivamente coincide con el tuyo.

Comment: si esta correcto gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución consiste en recorrer el arreglo revisando cada elemento (`vector[i]`) contra los elementos anteriores (`vector[:i]`).

Pongo el código en una función

```
def examinar(vector):
    for i in range(1, len(vector)):
        if vector[i] in vector[:i]:
            vector[i] = -1
    return vector
```

y lo pruebo

```
tests = [[],
         [100],
         [100, 100],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 2, 4],
         [5, 5, 5, 4, 5],
         [-1, -1, 3, 100, 200, 3]]

for test in tests:
    print(test, end=" => ")
    print(examinar(test))
```

produce

```
[] => []
[100] => [100]
[100, 100] => [100, -1]
[1, 2, 3, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 4] => [1, 2, -1, 4]
[5, 5, 5, 4, 5] => [5, -1, -1, 4, -1]
[-1, -1, 3, 100, 200, 3] => [-1, -1, 3, 100, 200, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que puedes crear una lista auxiliar donde vaya metiendo todos tus valores y después compares el elemento del vector con lo que tiene esa lista. Aquí el código de ejemplo:

```
vector = [1,100,1] 
li = []
longitud = len(vector)
for elemento in range(1,longitud):
    li.append(elemento) 
    if vector[elemento] in li: 
       vector[elemento] = -1 
print(vector)
```

La salida del vector sería:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva. ¡Saludos!

Comment: No lo había notado. Gracias @CandidMoe

Comment: Ya lo he editado para que no este fuera del rango. No debería tener problemas ahora ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente, no me gusta modificar una lista mientras se trabaja en ella. Mi propuesta es crear una nueva lista con el resultado, usando más o menos el algoritmo de @Candid-Moe:

```py
def find_duplicates(vector):
    return [x if x not in vector[:i] else -1
            for (i,x) in enumerate(vector)]

vector = [1,2,3,4,4,3]

new_vector = find_duplicates(vector)
num_modifs = sum(1 for x in new_vector if x==-1)
```